# Reading from a socket using buffered reader blocks

Tags: java, sockets, http, post

I am trying to create a http server in java.

The following is a fragment of my code.

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(80);
        while(true){
            Socket client = s.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            String input = in.readLine(), ff;
            System.out.println(input);
            while((ff = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(ff);
            }
            System.out.println("asd");
            in.close();
            client.close();
        }
```

Asd is never printed. When I try to do a POST on the local host, it sends me all the headers but doesn't send any content data. It just waits there doing nothing.

I am doing a post using Jquery

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1/",
        {
          name: "Donald Duck",
          city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

This is what is being printed on the screen:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5
Accept: */*
Origin: http://www.w3schools.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/47.0.2526.73 Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

That's it, nothing after this. It waits indefinitely at this point.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what is printed?  Shouldn't you be doing client.getOutputStream() and writing to it instead of System.out?

Comment: I just want to look at the content that my browser is sending to me as of for now. I need to process the data I am receiving further.. Updated the question and included the command line output. @bcampolo

Comment: Facing the same issue with Firefox as well.

Comment: If you're going to implement HTTP you need to read RFC 2616, especially the karts about content length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***My guess*** would be that your actual content/payload is not terminated by the expected line delimiters as described in [BufferedReader#readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

This blocks your `in.readLine()` invocation.

I would try to use the `read()` method instead and see if that helps. As in

```
while((value = in.read()) != -1) {
    char c = (char)value;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Edit: In fact, your question most likely duplicates this question: [Buffered Reader HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579823/buffered-reader-http-post)